# extract vimeo video id from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Though this question is available on SO, I am facing a little problem.I failed to extract the vimeo id using vimeo regex used here: [Vimeo Regex](http://jsbin.com/asuqic/184/edit?js,output)

### My codes I,m using now:

```
function vimeoProcess(url){
   var vimeoReg = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/;
   var match = url.match(vimeoReg);
   if (match){
      console.log(match[3]);
   }else{
      return "<span class='error'>error</span>";
   }
}
```

It does not consoles any thing.
Can any one help?

Comment: Are you calling that function? Because it works : http://jsfiddle.net/mvx9Lkjm/1/

Comment: Maybe your url string has a space or line break? Try to `.trim()` the url string or add the multiline flag `m` to your regex.

Comment: @JeremyThille i am using `https://player.vimeo.com/video/120911380`
But when i use `https://vimeo.com/channels/demoreels/120911380` it consoles `Refused to display 'https://vimeo.com/channels/demoreels/120911380' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Comment: That syntax is not present in the regex.

Comment: @kmsdev How can i do that

Comment: Oh no, that's something else. It's a cross-domain error. You're trying to load a resouce from another domain, and that other domain does not allow it (it wants "same origin") and explicitely refuses to display it.

Comment: @JeremyThille what can i do now?

Comment: Just designed another parser that should work better - see below.

Comment: Do you will use always the same url format? `https://player.vimeo.com/video/120911380`

Answer (score 3):

This "magical regex" is not so magical. It does not work with the URL you're using, for instance.

Here's another parser I just set up :

```js
var urls =
[
  "https://vimeo.com/11111111",
  "http://vimeo.com/11111111",
  "https://www.vimeo.com/11111111",
  "http://www.vimeo.com/11111111",
  "https://vimeo.com/channels/11111111",
  "http://vimeo.com/channels/11111111",
  "https://vimeo.com/channels/mychannel/11111111",
  "http://vimeo.com/channels/yourchannel/11111111",
  "https://vimeo.com/groups/name/videos/11111111",
  "http://vimeo.com/groups/name/videos/11111111",
  "https://vimeo.com/album/2222222/video/11111111",
  "http://vimeo.com/album/2222222/video/11111111",
  "https://vimeo.com/11111111?param=test",
  "http://vimeo.com/11111111?param=test",
  "http://vimeo.com/whatever/somethingelse/11111111?param=test",
  "http://www.player.vimeo.com/stuff/otherstuff/11111111"
];

$.each(urls, function(index, url) {
    
  var firstPart = url.split('?')[0].split("/");
  var vid = firstPart[firstPart.length - 1];
      
  $("table").append('<tr><td>'+url+'</td><td><span>'+vid+'</span></td></tr>');
});
```

```css
td   { font-family: monospace; }
span { background: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><th>Input</th><th>Result</th></tr>
</table>
```

**How it works :**

`url.split('?')` breaks `"http://vimeo.com/whatever/somethingelse/11111111?param=test"` into `["http://vimeo.com/whatever/somethingelse/11111111","param=test"]`

... or just `["http://vimeo.com/whatever/somethingelse/11111111"]` if there is no `?` in the URL.

Now `[0]` takes the first element of the array, which is `"http://vimeo.com/whatever/somethingelse/11111111"`.

Then we split that using `.split('/')`, which gives `["http:","","vimeo.com","whatever","somethingelse","11111111"]`

Now we just have to take the last element, which is our video ID :

```
vid = firstPart[firstPart.length - 1] // Gives "11111111"
```

Comment: Yes it does, I have just added one more test URL.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement Jon :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your current code, just change your regex to this one:

```
/https?:\/\/player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/(\d+)/gm
```

And use the first (the unique) matched element `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only deal with vimeo urls, you can also observe and consider that the only integers in their urls give you the video id.

```
var noquery = url.replace(/\?.*/,'') // remove anything after a ?
var id = noquery.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') // get all the digits
```

this would give you a simpler code until it breaks

it all depends if you want to extract the id from a url that you know is a video id or if you want to extract vimeo video urls among a bag of urls

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jeremy Thille's answer in the list.

The last step, could we use `pop()` to get the last element from that array, which could be like this:

```
let videoId = url.split('?')[0].split('/').pop()
```